# Prevent & disable iPhone iOS 9.2 from forced/ pushed auto downloading updates?

Tags: iphone, ios, software-update, auto-update

Prevent & disable iPhone iOS 9.2 from auto downloading updates?

iPhone 5 iOS 9.2 -

Today morning found it had auto downloaded 9.2.1 update - Around 200-400 MB.

I have a data cap with ISP so I dont want this happening on Apple's control.

How can I prevent & disable this?

I found these older articles but does not seem to have worked/ stopped the download.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7256669?tstart=0

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7250272?tstart=0

Comment: Thanks for posting the links to the discussions ... Yeah seems it's really hard to find a solid answer on this, I don't think the Wi-fi assist feature is relevant here and I don't think there's an "app" listed under Cellular Data, if you turned off all cellular data it would stop this but that's no fun!

Answer (score 2):

The closest I came was preventing all my iOS devices from *reaching* the update server. This envolves configuring your internet router in order to do so.

Configure your router to block the following domain: `mesu.apple.com`

Doing so will still allow your iDevice to talk to the Apple Store, allowing you to download/update iOS Apps.

Some routers (like mine) only allow me to block 'web sites' not domains. Luckily, that is all we need to do. Blocking `https://mesu.apple.com` also does the trick.

I would say blocking the whole domain is a cleaner solution if possible however.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  Please don't give link-only answers.  We're looking for answers that provide explanations as to why it answers the question as well as why it's the best answer.  Links can change over time and then we'll lose the question-answer context.  See [answer] for info on what makes up a good answer.  - From Review -

Comment: @fbara Fixed! Thanks for pointing that out. I am used to having to reference material where I obtained my information. But... behold! the link I had in my answer indeed expired and no longer worked.

Answer (score -1):

Really, if your iPhone is on Wi-Fi and an update is available, it will download the update when you're probably asleep (2:00-4:00AM). There is no way to disable this.

A workaround would be to turn Wi-Fi on your iPhone off when you go to bed.

Comment: So this is a new thing that iOS 9.2 does automatically? 
So, on 3G, WiFi disabled, it wont do so?

Comment: @AlexS It's not new for iOS 9.2, but I'm not sure when this started. If you turn your Wi-Fi off it likely shouldn't download the update over LTE or 3G.

Comment: Just make sure that Use Cellular Data is not turned on in the iTunes and App Store menu of your device's Settings.

Comment: @angelplayer Actually, I think that that's different. One can't even download an update over cellular if he wanted to, so iOS doesn't do it by itself.