# IOS Settings App Notification Acknowledgement (red dot elimination)

Tags: ios, notifications

The settings icon indicates a little red dot with the number of notifications.  How does one acknowledge the notification and turn off the red dot? I want to avoid upgrading IOS and would like to remove the red dot.  Suggestions are appreciated: thank you

Comment: You need to delete the update, then block the server - see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/225334/prevent-disable-iphone-ios-9-2-from-forced-pushed-auto-downloading-updates

Answer (score -1):

The red dot in notification bar because of notifications in secure zone check it once

Comment: This doesn't really make sense.  Can you edit your answer to address the problem in the OP's question?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different and thank you for your answer. :) Unfortunately, short answers such as this don't really provide enough detail or context to help many users. If possible, it'd be good if you could add some more info such as _how_ to do what you're suggesting and _how_ it resolves the OP's question. Also, you may want to read [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for tips on providing answers here.